# How to check if a block of lines has a particular keyword using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-requests, file-handling

I am checking a text file with blocks of commands as following -

```
File start - 
!
interface Vlan100
 description XYZ
 ip vrf forwarding XYZ
 ip address 10.208.56.62 255.255.255.192
!
interface Vlan101
 description ABC
 ip vrf forwarding ABC
 ip address 10.208.55.126 255.255.255.192
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
File End
```

and I want to create a txt file where if in source file I am getting a pattern **vrf forwarding ABC** output should be **interface Vlan101**

as of now what I have done following script but it showing only the line which contains the pattern.

```
import re
f = open("output_file.txt","w") #output file to be generated
shakes = open("input_file.txt","r") #input file to read
for lines in shakes:
    if re.match("(.*)ABC(.*)",lines):
        f.write(lines)
f.close()
```

Comment: If you get the pattern vrf forwarding ABC  your output to be written to file is 'interface Vlan101'? Could you explain your output file format. as well?

Comment: in your for loop, you need save interface info, then when match your expect string, you can print it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest: read the file, cut where `!` is, then for each of those, if there's the desired text, get the first line:

```
with open("input_file.txt") as r, open("output_file.txt", "w") as w:
    txt = r.read()
    result = [block.strip().split("\n")[0]
              for block in txt.split('!')
              if 'vrf forwarding ABC' in block]
    w.write("\n".join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, I imagine that you want to replace any instances of "interface Vlan101" with "vrf forwarding ABC". In this case, I had **test.txt** as the input file and **out.txt** as the output file with all the replaced instances as was needed. I used a list comprehension--with a list string method-- to replace the substrings of "interface Vlan101" with "vrf forwarding ABC".

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

new_lines = [line.replace("interface Vlan101", "vrf forwarding ABC" for line in lines]

with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
    f1.writelines(new_lines)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the interface, you can do following as well.

```
#Read File
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

#Capture 'interfaces'
interfaces =  [i for i in lines if i.strip().startswith('inter')]

#Write it to a file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(interfaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code you are going through the document line by line.

If you want to parse blocks (between "!"-signs) you could split the blocks into lines first (though if it's a really large document, you may need to consider something else as this will read the entire document into memory)

```
import re

f = open("output_file.txt","w") #output file to be generated
source = open("input_file.txt","r") #input file to read

lines = "".join(source) #creates a string from the document
shakes = lines.replace("\n","").replace("! ","\n")
# remove all newlines and create new ones from "!"-block delimiter

# retrieve all text before "vrf forwarding ABC"
finds = re.findall("(.*)vrf forwarding ABC",shakes)

# return start of line
# if the part you want is the same length in all, 
# then you could use find[:17] instead of 
# find to get only the beginning. otherwise you need to modify your
# regex to only take the first 2 words of the line.

for find in finds:
    f.write(find)
f.close()
```

Alternatively, if you want to use match per line, you can do the same as above, however instead of replacing "!" with new line, you can just split it, and then use the previous code and go line by line.

Hope this helps!